# Error: value computed is not used [-Werror=unused-value]

Tags: arrays, c, string, compiler-errors

Ive written this code to try and read if there are any duplicate letters in a word, but I keep coming across this error:

Error: value computed is not used [-Werror=unused-value]

The line in question is:

```
arr[(int)(str[i])++];
```

The whole code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[30];
    printf("Enter your String:");
    scanf("%[^\n]",str);
    int i;
    int arr[256]={0};
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==' '){
            continue;
            arr[(int)(str[i])++];
        }
    }
    printf("Repeated character in a string are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>1)
        {
          printf("%c occurs %d times\n",(char)(i),arr[i]);
        }}
        return 0;
}
```

Here is the error message from the console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpMOW.png

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: what is that line supposed to do?

Comment: There are several mistakes. a) `arr[(int)(str[i])++];` should be `arr[(unsigned char)str[i]]++;` note the `++` is repositioned. b) this immediately follows `continue;` so reposition it, c) `if(arr[i]>1)` should be `if(arr[i]>0)`.

Comment: ...also `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` should be `scanf("%29[^\n]",str);`. Never write code that is open to buffer overflow exploits.

Comment: @WeatherVane I did arr[(unsigned char)str[i]]++; but im getting unassigned undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: After I made the changes mentioned, the program does what it is supposed to (gives letter frequency).

Comment: @WeatherVane im also getting   error: expected expression before 'char'        arr[((unassigned) (char))[str[i]]]++;

Comment: @WeatherVane  I dont understand when u said b) this immediately follows continue;

Comment: No statement that immediatley follows `continue;` can ever be executed, because control has been transferred to the loop iteration. In the same way: `return; puts("Hello");` will never output anything.

Comment: regarding: `int i; ...  for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)`  the function `strlen()` returns a `size_t` NOT a `int`

Comment: regarding: `if(str[i]==' '){
            continue;
            arr[(int)(str[i])++];`   The statement: `arr[(int)(str[i])++];` will never be executed because `continue` will cause execution to jump back to the prior looping statement.

Comment: please do npt run statements together, like" `)}`  It makes it difficult to see the full format of the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to the code, shown in comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main()
{
    char str[30];
    printf("Enter your String:");
    scanf("%29[^\n]", str);             // limit the input length
    int i;
    int arr[256] = { 0 };
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            continue;
        }
        // this line was repositioned so that it can execute
        // char can be signed, so don't index by a negative value
        // the post-increment should apply to the `arr[]` array element
        arr[ (unsigned char)str[i] ]++;
    }
    printf("Repeated character in a string are:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > 0)                  // inform *any* usage
        {
            // (char)i gets promoted to int anyway
            printf("%c occurs %d times\n", i, arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Session:

```
Enter your String:one two
Repeated character in a string are:
e occurs 1 times
n occurs 1 times
o occurs 2 times
t occurs 1 times
w occurs 1 times
```

Comment: For my task, i just need only the duplicated letters to be printed. 
What do i change

Comment: I see, however I hope this answer has still helped you. Change the `if(arr[i] > 0)` back to `if(arr[i] > 1)`

Comment: Thanks it really did help :) also im trying to do an if condition where if there are no duplicate letters it displays: "No duplicates found" i tried if(arr[i]>0) { printf("No duplicates found") but it would still show up on both outcomes

Comment: You can add a variable that flags the detections. For example `int dups = 0;` and then in the code block `if(arr[i] > 1) { dups++; }` and check `dups` afterwards.